# How can I use Global Filters and Column Filters at the same time with Tanstack Tables (React Table JS)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, datatables, tanstack

I made a table with the functionalities I wanted. Now I want to implement a column filter using a select that will generate its options based on another function I have to make. Now I am testing it, seeing if I can make it work, but after a lot of attempts, I haven't been able. I am using React JS.

This is the select I'm having problems with, I'm pretty sure the problem is there, but I can't figure it out. Everything else works OK.

```
         <select
                id="dates"
                className="bg-gray-20 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-red-300 focus:border-red-300 block w-full p-2.5"
                value={columnFilters[0].value}
                onChange={(e) => {
                    setColumnFilters([
                        {
                            id: "eventAssembleDate",
                            value: e.target.value,
                        },
                    ]);
                    
                }}
               >
                <option value="">Filtrar por cualquier día</option>
                <option value="244">25/12</option>
                <option value="26/12">26/12</option>
        </select>
```

And this is the full table component code:

```
import {
    flexRender,
    getCoreRowModel,
    getFilteredRowModel,
    useReactTable,
    getPaginationRowModel,
    getSortedRowModel,
} from "@tanstack/react-table";
import { getOrders } from "./DashboardApi";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BiSortAlt2 } from "react-icons/bi";
import { BiSortDown } from "react-icons/bi";
import { BiSortUp } from "react-icons/bi";

const columns = [
    {
        accessorKey: "clientName",
        header: "NOMBRE DEL CLIENTE",
        cell: (props) => <p>{props.getValue()}</p>,
    },
    {
        accessorKey: "assembleTeamId",
        header: "ARMAR/RETIRAR",
        cell: (props) => <p>{props.getValue()}</p>,
    },
    {
        accessorKey: "eventAssembleDate",
        header: "DÍA Y HORARIO",
        cell: (props) => <p>{props.getValue()}</p>,
    },
];

const OrderTable = ({ cookies }) => {
    // Get table data
    const [data, setData] = useState({});
    const token = cookies.get("token");
    const [filtering, setFiltering] = useState("");
    const [columnFilters, setColumnFilters] = useState([
        {
            id: "eventAssembleDate",
            value: "",
        },
    ]);

    const [sorting, setSorting] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async (token) => {
            const data = await getOrders(token);
            setData(data);
        };

        fetchData(token);
    }, []);

    const table = useReactTable({
        data,
        columns,
        state: {
            sorting: sorting,
            globalFilter: filtering,
            columnFilters: columnFilters,
        },
        getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
        getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
        getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),
        getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
        onSortingChange: setSorting,
        onGlobalFilterChange: setFiltering,
        onColumnFiltersChange: setColumnFilters,
    });

    return (
        <>
            <select
                id="dates"
                className="bg-gray-20 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-red-300 focus:border-red-300 block w-full p-2.5"
                value={columnFilters[0].value}
                onChange={(e) => {
                    setColumnFilters([
                        {
                            id: "eventAssembleDate",
                            value: e.target.value,
                        },
                    ]);
                    
                }}
            >
                <option value="">Filtrar por cualquier día</option>
                <option value="244">25/12</option>
                <option value="26/12">26/12</option>
            </select>
            <div className="overflow-x-auto shadow-md sm:rounded-lg">
                <div className="relative">
                    <div className="absolute inset-y-0 start-0 flex items-center ps-3 pointer-events-none">
                        <svg
                            className="w-4 h-4 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400"
                            aria-hidden="true"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            fill="none"
                            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                        >
                            <path
                                stroke="currentColor"
                                strokeLinecap="round"
                                strokeLinejoin="round"
                                strokeWidth="2"
                                d="m19 19-4-4m0-7A7 7 0 1 1 1 8a7 7 0 0 1 14 0Z"
                            />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        value={filtering}
                        onChange={(e) => setFiltering(e.target.value)}
                        className="block w-full p-4 ps-10 text-sm text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg"
                        placeholder="Buscar cualquier atributo de la tabla..."
                    />
                </div>
                <table className="w-full text-sm text-left rtl:text-right text-gray-500 table-auto">
                    <thead className="text-xs text-gray-700 uppercase bg-gray-50">
                        {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
                            <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
                                {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => (
                                    <th
                                        scope="col"
                                        className="px-6 py-3 cursor-pointer"
                                        key={header.id}
                                        onClick={header.column.getToggleSortingHandler()}
                                    >
                                        {header.column.columnDef.header}{" "}
                                        {
                                            {
                                                asc: <BiSortDown size={15} />,
                                                desc: <BiSortUp size={15} />,
                                            }[
                                                header.column.getIsSorted() ??
                                                    null
                                            ]
                                        }
                                        {!header.column.getIsSorted() && (
                                            <BiSortAlt2 size={15} />
                                        )}
                                    </th>
                                ))}
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
                            <tr
                                className="odd:bg-white odd:dark:bg-gray-900 even:bg-gray-50"
                                key={row.id}
                            >
                                {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                                    <td className="px-6 py-4" key={cell.id}>
                                        {flexRender(
                                            cell.column.columnDef.cell,
                                            cell.getContext()
                                        )}
                                    </td>
                                ))}
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-col items-end">
                <div className="inline-flex mt-2 xs:mt-0">
                    <button
                        className="flex items-center justify-center px-3 h-8 text-sm font-medium text-white bg-gray-800 rounded-s hover:bg-gray-900"
                        disabled={!table.getCanPreviousPage()}
                        onClick={() => table.previousPage()}
                    >
                        <svg
                            className="w-3.5 h-3.5 me-2 rtl:rotate-180"
                            aria-hidden="true"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            fill="none"
                            viewBox="0 0 14 10"
                        >
                            <path
                                stroke="currentColor"
                                strokeLinecap="round"
                                strokeLinejoin="round"
                                strokeWidth="2"
                                d="M13 5H1m0 0 4 4M1 5l4-4"
                            />
                        </svg>
                        Anterior
                    </button>
                    <button
                        className="flex items-center justify-center px-3 h-8 text-sm font-medium text-white bg-gray-800 border-0 border-s border-gray-700 rounded-e hover:bg-gray-900"
                        disabled={!table.getCanNextPage()}
                        onClick={() => table.nextPage()}
                    >
                        Siguiente
                        <svg
                            className="w-3.5 h-3.5 ms-2 rtl:rotate-180"
                            aria-hidden="true"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            fill="none"
                            viewBox="0 0 14 10"
                        >
                            <path
                                stroke="currentColor"
                                strokeLinecap="round"
                                strokeLinejoin="round"
                                strokeWidth="2"
                                d="M1 5h12m0 0L9 1m4 4L9 9"
                            />
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <span className="text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
                    Página{" "}
                    <span className="font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                        {table.getState().pagination.pageIndex + 1}
                    </span>{" "}
                    de{" "}
                    <span className="font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                        {table.getPageCount()}
                    </span>{" "}
                </span>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default OrderTable;
```

I tried logging the columnFilters const, and it seems like it is working fine, but when I select the option, the table just turns blank.

I also tried writting the `value` of the options in the select in the Global Filter that works, and it filtered the table like it should. Its just the select for the Column Filter that doesn't work.